# is site cloaking possible with a .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cloaking

i have created a wordpress site within a folder on a site and am having trouble moving the database so was looking in to ways of cloaking the sites url on every page with a .htaccess file. at the moment the site is a beta at www.christopherwaller.com. I wanted to look into removing the ugly URLS with page-id etc....

Does anyone know if this is possible. or if the .htaccess file is not the way to go

much appreciated

N

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "url cloaking"? Do you mean something like this? http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-friendly-url-structure/4556/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in wordpress features, have a look at Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to change from

`http://www.christopherwaller.com/wordpress/?page_id=240`
to
`http://www.christopherwaller.com/wordpress/about`

Just navigate to your admin control panel, click on Configuration on the left menu, and then on Permalinks.

Fill the 'Custom' field with `/%postname%` and the links should appear as your expect.